# Asymptotic expansion of the inverse of $x\mapsto x+x^{\small\sqrt2}+x^2$ near zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, inverse-function

<sup>*This is a follow-up to my previous question ["Asymptotic expansion of the inverse of $x\mapsto x+x^\phi$ near zero"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3946567/19661).*</sup>

Consider a continuous real-valued monotone increasing function $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ satisfying $f\big(x+x^{\small\sqrt2}+x^2\big)=x.$

[image]

I am interested in an asymptotic expansion of $f(z)$ for $z\to0^+$ in terms of powers of $z$. I was able to find a few initial terms by manually balancing coefficients:
$$f(z)=z-z^{\small\sqrt2}+\sqrt2\;z^{\small\unicode{x202f}2\unicode{x202f}\sqrt2-1}-z^2+\mathcal O\big(z^{\small\unicode{x202f}3\unicode{x202f}\sqrt2-2}\big), \quad z\to0^+.\tag{$\diamond$}$$
Computing next terms in an *ad hoc* fashion quickly becomes tedious, so I am looking for a more systematic approach that would allow to obtain a general formula for the terms of this series. I expect it to be a mix of integer powers of $z$ and irrational powers involving $\sqrt2$. Also, I would like to know the radius of convergence of that series.

More generally, I am looking for a uniform approach for inverting generalized polynomials of a single variable that may contain both rational and irrational powers.

Comment: The inversion formula for a trinomial is known:
$$f(z) = \sum_{i \geq 0, \, j \geq 0}
 \frac
  {(-1)^{i + j} (a_{i, j})_{i + j}}
  {a_{i, j}} \frac {z^{a_{i, j}}} {i! j!},$$
where $a_{i, j} = i + (\sqrt 2 - 1) j + 1$ and $(a)_i$ is the rising factorial. We can evaluate $\sum_{i \geq 0} (a_{i, j})_{i + j} z^i/(a_{i, j} i!)$ in terms of the hypergeometric function ${_2 F_1}$ and take the asymptotic expansion of ${_2 F_1}$ to find the radius of convergence. The double series converges absolutely for $|z| < z_0 \approx .0595483$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Look at $$f(x)=x(1+x^{\sqrt2-1}+x)\in S=\Bbb{R}[[x,x^{\sqrt2-1}]]$$
The exponents are well-ordered.

Let $$\phi : x\to f(x), \ x^{\sqrt2-1} \to x^{\sqrt2-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {\sqrt2-1 \choose k} (x^{\sqrt2-1}+x)^k$$
Then $\phi$ is an injective endomorphism of $S$, since $\phi(x^a)= x^a(1+O(x^{\sqrt2-1})+O(x))$ then $\phi$ is surjective. Whence $\phi(f^{-1}(x))=x$ for some $f^{-1}(x)\in S$.

It remains to find the coefficients one by one as you did. I don't see much reason to believe that $f^{-1}(x)$ converges for some $x>0$.

Comment: $S$ is the ring of formal series of the form $G(x,x^{\sqrt2-1})=\sum_{a,b\ge 0} c_{a,b}x^a (x^{\sqrt2-1})^b$, in this ring we have $f(x)^{\sqrt2-1}=x^{\sqrt2-1} \sum_{k\ge 0} {\sqrt2-1 \choose k} (x^{\sqrt2-1}+x)^k\in S$ so the endomorphism $\phi(G(x,x^{\sqrt2-1}))=G(f(x),f(x)^{\sqrt2-1})$ is well-defined, obviously injective, and surjective. Then $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is the formal series expansion of the inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

**Some thoughts**

**Conjecture**: When $y>0$ is sufficiently small, the unique positive real solution of $x + x^{\sqrt{2}} + x^2 = y$ is given by
\begin{align}
x &= y + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}}{\mathrm{d} y^{k-1}}\Big[(y^{\sqrt{2}} + y^2)^k\Big]\\
&= y - (y^{\sqrt{2}} + y^2) + (\sqrt{2}y^{2\sqrt{2}-1} + (2+\sqrt{2})y^{\sqrt{2}+1} + 2y^3) - \cdots \tag{1}
\end{align}

**Motivation**: The equation is written as $x = y + (-1)(x^{\sqrt{2}} + x^2)$. By the Lagrange reversion theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem),
we guess (1).

Numerical experiment using Maple: When $y = \frac{1}{100}$, the solution of $x + x^{\sqrt{2}} + x^2 = y$ is
$x_0 \approx 0.008704284007$,
while $y + \sum_{k=1}^{20} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}}{\mathrm{d} y^{k-1}}\Big[(y^{\sqrt{2}} + y^2)^k\Big]
\approx 0.008704284006$.

However, when $y$ is larger, it may fail. For example, $y = 1/2$,
$y + \sum_{k=1}^{5} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1}}{\mathrm{d} y^{k-1}}\Big[(y^{\sqrt{2}} + y^2)^k\Big]\approx -19.46221804$.

So I guess we need sufficiently small $y$.

**Further work**: 1) What is the ROC of the series (1)? 2) Prove (or disprove) if it is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach:

We have to solve ( with $y=f$)

$$y+ y^{\sqrt{2}} + y^2 = x$$

Let's take a simpler equation $y - y^2 = x$, equivalent to $y = x + F(y)$,
so should have
$$y = x + F(x+F(y)) = x+F(x+F(x+F(y)))= x+F(x+F(x+\ldots )))$$
(note that $F$ is not a linear operator, if it were, we would have the Neumann series for $(I-F)^{-1}$), still we have a fixed point problem that is solved with iterations.
Using this iteration approach we get the Taylor series for the solution  $y = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4 x}}{2}$.

We might use this approach for
$$y = x - y^{\sqrt{2}}- y^2 = x - ( x- y^{\sqrt{2}}- y^2)^{\sqrt{2}} -( x- y^{\sqrt{2}}- y^2)^2= \cdots $$

$\bf{Added:}$

The equation $y = T(y)= x - y^{\sqrt{2}} - y^2$ can be solve by successive approximations
$y_{n+1} = T(y_n)$. For instance, we can consider $y_0=x$, $y_1 = x - x^{\sqrt{2}} - x^2$, $y_2 = x - (x - x^{\sqrt{2}} - x^2)^{\sqrt{2}} - (x - x^{\sqrt{2}} - x^2)^2$, etc. One should figure out (easy) how to expand
$$( x+ \sum_{\alpha>1} a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha} )^{\beta} = x^{\beta} ( 1 + \sum_{\gamma >0} c_{\gamma} x^{\gamma})^{\beta}$$
We use the expansion
$$(1+ \sum_{\gamma} t_{\gamma})^{\beta}  = \sum_{\beta_1 < \ldots \beta_r}\sum_l \frac{\beta(\beta-1)\cdots (\beta- |l|+1)}{l!} t_{\gamma_1}^{l_1}\cdots t_{\gamma_r}^{l_r} $$
We are dealing with formal series with exponents positive and $\to \infty$.

To be continued...

Comment: Is my answer unclear ? The inverse is a formal series in $x,x^{\sqrt2-1}$ whose truncation is obviously the asymptotic expansion near $0$

Comment: @reuns Sorry, your answer is too concise and too technical for me. I would appreciate if you could expand it and make it more explanatory.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov which part is unclear ?